# How to use the slice of a results(array) from a middle layer

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, slice

I know that we can use the get_layer() to build a new model, but my problem is a little different:

I simplified my model:

```
import keras
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5,6],[1,2,3,4,5,6],[1,2,3,4,5,6]])
x = keras.layers.Input(shape=(6,))
y = keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x * 1)(x)
z = keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x * 1)(y[:,4])
model = keras.Model(x,[y,z])
model.compile(optimizer='sgd',loss='mean_squared_error')
model.predict(a)
```

if I remove the line of 'z', the model works just fine. Otherwise with encounter the following error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-74-7fc86ac55867> in <module>()
----> 1 model = keras.Model(x,[y,z])
    2 model.compile(optimizer='sgd',loss='mean_squared_error')

~/.conda/envs/21/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    89                 warnings.warn('Update your `' + object_name +
    90                               '` call to the Keras 2 API: ' + signature, stacklevel=2)
---> 91             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    92         wrapper._original_function = func
    93         return wrapper

~/.conda/envs/21/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/network.py in __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    89                 'inputs' in kwargs and 'outputs' in kwargs):
    90             # Graph network
---> 91             self._init_graph_network(*args, **kwargs)
    92         else:
    93             # Subclassed network

~/.conda/envs/21/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/network.py in _init_graph_network(self, inputs, outputs, name)
    233         # Keep track of the network's nodes and layers.
    234         nodes, nodes_by_depth, layers, layers_by_depth = _map_graph_network(
--> 235             self.inputs, self.outputs)
    236         self._network_nodes = nodes
    237         self._nodes_by_depth = nodes_by_depth

~/.conda/envs/21/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/network.py in _map_graph_network(inputs, outputs)
1410                   layer=layer,
1411                   node_index=node_index,
-> 1412                   tensor_index=tensor_index)
1413 
1414     for node in reversed(nodes_in_decreasing_depth):

~/.conda/envs/21/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/network.py in build_map(tensor, finished_nodes, nodes_in_progress, layer, node_index, tensor_index)
1397             tensor_index = node.tensor_indices[i]
1398             build_map(x, finished_nodes, nodes_in_progress, layer,
-> 1399                       node_index, tensor_index)
1400 
1401         finished_nodes.add(node)

~/.conda/envs/21/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/network.py in build_map(tensor, finished_nodes, nodes_in_progress, layer, node_index, tensor_index)
1369             ValueError: if a cycle is detected.
1370         """
-> 1371         node = layer._inbound_nodes[node_index]
1372 
1373         # Prevent cycles.

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_inbound_nodes'
```

Can anybody tell me why does that happen and how to fix it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just slice the tensor within the `Lambda` layer:

```
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
             [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
             [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]])
x = keras.layers.Input(shape=(6,))
y = keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x * 1)(x)
z = keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x[:, 4] * 1)(y)
model = keras.Model(x, [y, z])
model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mean_squared_error')
model.predict(a)
```

Comment: I tried to use _tf.slice_, but apparently yours is better. But I have one more question, I want to convert each value in z into one hot, and then find their sum as an input passing to another dense layer. e.g. **z.output=array([2,1,2]) --> r=[0,0,1]+[0,1,0]+[0,0,1]=[0,1,2] --> d=Dense()(r)**  I tried to use **tf.one_hot** and **tf.reduce_sum** but always got an **error:AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_inbound_nodes'** Do you know why that happened and how to fix it?

Comment: I found that when I put the tf.one_hot and tf.reduce_sum into a Lambda, it works! It seems that Lambda is a very good layer, thanks!